# Creating a camera effect in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, sprite-kit, cgpoint

I am trying to create a game that scrolls when the user's touch is close enough to the top of the iPhone screen. This is what I have so far:

```
 -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

   CGPoint currentLocation = [currentTouch locationInView:currentTouch.view];

   if (currentLocation.y > 100) {

    _world.position.y - 25;



   }
}
```

So current location is the CGPoint derived from the touch registered in my touchesBegan method. I took the y of that (x doesn't matter I don't think) and told it to scoot the SKNode everything in my scene is attached to down. Nothing is happening and I get the warning that 'the expression result is unused' during my then statement. I'm just winging it on this one. Any ideas why it doesn't work or better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You do not assign the result of this subtraction, so the result is discarded:

```
_world.position.y - 25;
```

To actually assign this new position:

```
CGFloat newY = _world.position.y - 25;
_world.position = CGPointMake(_world.position.x, newY);
```

Comment: I see now that I was assigning it wrong. Thanks! I'm still not getting any movement from my node though. It seems like my currentLocation might be off too. Any idea?